# Multiple 'cmd.exe' commands in one ShellExecuteEx under Delphi

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

I'm trying to have multiple commands executed in one ShellExecuteEx.

Each command has its own parameters.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to write the commands to a temporary file with .bat extension and pass that file name to ShellExecuteEx.

The alternative involves trying to do it with arguments to cmd.exe. That's going to involve /C, the [& or && operators](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php) and argument quoting hell.

My recommendation is to seek an easy life and create a temporary file with your script in.

Answer (score 0):

There are **3 syntaxes** for conditional execution. Command 1 and 2 you would replace with different commands.

**1 -** Place an ampersand `&` in between two command to make command2 execute right after command1.

**2 -** Place two ampersands `&&` between two command to make command2 execute only if command1 finished successfully.

**3 -** Place two pipes `||` between two command to make command2 execute only if command1 fails.

**Run like this :**

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'CMD',PChar(c/ **"** command1 **syntaxe** command2 **"**), nil, sw_ShowNormal);
```